# Why is the file I am attempting to write "non-existing"?

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

I have a custom config file in my CI application.  In my web application's admin panel, I want to have a form that I can use to change the values of the config array of the custom file.  My problem right now is that the write_file function always returns false and I don't know why.  I am pretty sure I am writing the path in the function correctly and the config directory is not read-only(this is wamp, so windows).  The file definitely exists. What am I doing wrong?

This is application/controllers/config/assets.php

```
$file = FCPATH . 'application\config\assets_fe.php';
if(is_writable($file)) {
    $open = fopen($file, 'W');
    if(!fwrite($open, $frontend)){
        echo "Could not write file!";
    } else {
        echo "File written!";
    }
} else {
    echo "File not writable!";
}
```

This is a screenshot of the file in it's location in windows explorer.
[image: config folder]

I have tried the following file paths in the write_file function:

```
write_file(FCPATH.'application/config/assets_fe.php', $frontend, 'W');
write_file('application/config/assets_fe.php', $frontend, 'W');
write_file('./application/config/assets_fe.php', $frontend, 'W');
```

None of the above file paths have worked... could it be something else?

FYI:  FCPATH = 'W:\wamp\www\zeus\' and it's defined by CI's front controller to return the path of that file.

Update:  I tried using just the native PHP version and it's saying that the file or directory does not exist.  Maybe I am using the wrong path.  What should it be?

Comment: yes, config is writable.

Comment: Please fix the code in your question.

Comment: This could be helpful, though its not what you are trying. [Database based Config library](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/131762/)

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Oh. PHP inside strings... I thought it was just formatted very badly.

Comment: maybe your user group have no permission to write on disk. first check it out

Comment: why write the config on to a file? why not store it in a db table ?

Comment: @Majid - I have used the same function in other scripts on the same disk.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291: Can you go to the Security tab in the file properties window? What user does your web server run as, and is that user listed as someone who has permissions to write to that file? What does `is_writable(FCPATH.'application\config\assets_fe.php')` return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple, you are passing an invalid mode, captial **W**, to [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). It should be a lowercase **w**. So what's happening is `fopen` is returning `false`, then you're passing that to `fwrite` instead of a resource, causing it to return `false`.

Just change

```
$open = fopen($file, 'W');
```

to

```
$open = fopen($file, 'w');
```

You might also test the result of `fopen`

```
if(!$open)
    echo 'Could not open file';
```

You could also try `file_put_contents` since you don't do anything else w/ the file handle.

```
$file = FCPATH.'application\config\assets_fe.php';
if(is_writable($file)){
    if(!file_put_contents($file, $frontend)) {
        echo "Could not write file!";
    } else {
         echo "File written!";
    }
} else {
    echo "File not writable!";
}
```

Comment: Oh, passing `"W"` in fact produces the incorrect error message `"failed to open stream: No such file or directory in"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use set_item to write into config file.

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

for arrays:

```
$this->config->set_item('ftp_frontend', array(...));
```

Its here in [config](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html).

Comment: But that won't save the actual file, that will just let you use it further down in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to write in config.php file. Instead of writting in `config.php` file, you can user CI configuration class to override value of config file like below

**For single item**

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

**For array item**

```
$this->config->set_item('item_array', array(...));
```